# how does peers in hyperledger validates the transaction?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am new to hyperledger so sorry for the silly question.

In the transaction flow

1)How does the endorsing peer/any peer know the transaction is signed by the authorized peer/correct key?

Can anyone help me understand the steps of validations and how does it come to know if the transaction is signed by correct key/incorrect key?

2)does the orderer also validates the transaction or just creates blocks and forwards the blocks to the leader peer?

3)What is the role of BCCSP in the network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1)How does the endorsing peer/any peer know the transaction is signed by the authorized peer/correct key?
>
> Can anyone help me understand the steps of validations and how does it come to know if the transaction is signed by correct key/incorrect key?

Each transaction contains `SerializedIdentity`, which for example in case of conventional MSP (based on X.509) it contains certificate signed by CA. Root ca certificates preloaded in genesis blocks. Therefore when it comes to transaction validation it extracts certificate verifies CA signature on this certificate, next gets public key from certificate and validates signature on transaction.

> 2)does the orderer also validates the transaction or just creates blocks and forwards the blocks to the leader peer?

Orderes validate ACL to check that whoever submit transaction has channel write privileges. Also orderers validates and checks transaction which deals with channel configuration, since they also have might have to apply it. Other than these transactions content completely opaque to ordering nodes and in particular ordering nodes are not trying to verify endorsement policy for example.

> 3)What is the role of BCCSP in the network?

BCCSP stand for `BlockChain Crypto Service Provider` essentially this is only an abstraction aims to provide more plugability and flexibility. The key essence is to present an API which brings implementation of crypto primitives such as signatures, signatures verification and hashing algorithms in abstract way allowing easy replacement of such if needed.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation,But why do Peer and orderer Binaries use BCCSP?

Comment: They need it to provide crypto services or more exactly concrete implementation for crypto primitives.